# Change color after revealing text in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to reach some specific results with my code but I can't find what I am doing wrong. It would be very helpful if you could correct me.

So I have made these rows that you can click and open. The orange rows open and the title becomes blue. I want the opposite thing for the blue rows. I mean I want the row to open and the title to become orange.

Thanks in advance. This is my first post here :)

Here is my code

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion2");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  font-family: default;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #F7A600;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 26px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #F7A600;
}

.accordion:after {
  content: '\23F7';
  font-weight: bold;
  float: float;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.active:after,
.accordion {
  content: "\23F6";
}

.accordion2 {
  font-family: default;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #009ACB;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 26px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
}

.active,
.accordion2:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #009ACB;
}

.accordion2:after {
  content: '\23F7';
  font-weight: bold;
  float: float;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after,
.accordion2 {
  content: "\23F6";
}

.panel-1 {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  color: #424241;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Γενικές Πληροφορίες</button>
<div class="panel-1">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion2">Αίτια</button>
<div class="panel-1">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">ΔΕΠ-Υ στα παιδιά</button>
<div class="panel-1">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion2">ΔΕΠ-Υ στους ενήλικες</button>
<div class="panel-1">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Συννοσηρότητα</button>
<div class="panel-1">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion2">Διάγνωση</button>
<div class="panel-1">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Φαρμακευτική αγωγή</button>
<div class="panel-1">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion2">Ψυχοθεραπεία</button>
<div class="panel-1">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Coaching για τη ΔΕΠ-Υ</button>
<div class="panel-1">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: try `.active.accordion2, .accordion2:hover` CSS selector, because `.active` alone has 2 definitions, the second overwriting the first (you should also replace the first with `.active.accordion, .accordion:hover`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you defined style like this:

```
.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #F7A600;
}
```

A little later you wrote this:

```
.active, .accordion2:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #009ACB;
}
```

Basically you are styling the `active` class twice and the 2nd one overwrites the first one. You can do this instead to fix it:

```
.active, .accordion:hover, .accordion2:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.accordion:hover, .accordion2.active {
  color: #F7A600;
}

.accordion2:hover, .accordion.active  {
  color: #009ACB;
}
```

In case you do not fully understand the different css selectors I would recommend to read about them here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
.accordion2.active {
  color: #F7A600;
}
```

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion2");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  font-family: default;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #F7A600;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 26px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
}

.accordion2.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #F7A600;
}

.accordion:after {
  content: '\23F7';
  font-weight: bold;
  float: float;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.active:after,
.accordion {
  content: "\23F6";
}

.accordion2 {
  font-family: default;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #009ACB;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 26px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
}

.active,
.accordion2:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #009ACB;
}

.accordion2:after {
  content: '\23F7';
  font-weight: bold;
  float: float;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after,
.accordion2 {
  content: "\23F6";
}

.panel-1 {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  color: #424241;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Γενικές Πληροφορίες</button>
<div class="panel-1">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion2">Αίτια</button>
<div class="panel-1">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">ΔΕΠ-Υ στα παιδιά</button>
<div class="panel-1">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion2">ΔΕΠ-Υ στους ενήλικες</button>
<div class="panel-1">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Συννοσηρότητα</button>
<div class="panel-1">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion2">Διάγνωση</button>
<div class="panel-1">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Φαρμακευτική αγωγή</button>
<div class="panel-1">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion2">Ψυχοθεραπεία</button>
<div class="panel-1">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Coaching για τη ΔΕΠ-Υ</button>
<div class="panel-1">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there also a way to have the first row open and the others closed?